# How to achieve coordinator layout scroll effect in ionic?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

How to achieve android coordinator layout scroll in ionic app with angular 4 Is there is any java script or type script library ?

[image]

Comment: There's no "AngularJS 4", it's called "Angular" which has a version 4. Please do not tag questions as both AngularJS (1.x) and Angular (2+) unless you're asking about migration process.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is called the expandable header, please follow these links for tutorials.

[Creating a Custom Expandable Header Component for Ionic 2 & 3](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/)

[Parallax Effect Directive in Ionic 2](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-directive-in-ionic-2-parallax-header/)